# Problema con pasar datos de modal -> javascript -> PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo este codigo para el modal en html, pues a la hora de cargar el modal no logro capturar la informacion de los campos en javascript para poder enviarlos a PHP e ingresar la informacion a la tabla. Me sale error 404 en el browser.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-placement="left" title="Agregar">
        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Nuevo
        </button>


     <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-m " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-m" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><strong><span class='fa fa-plus'></span> Agregar Nuevo Role</strong></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="Detalle">Tipo de Role</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tiporole1" id="tiporole1" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="Detalle">Detalle</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="detalle1" name="detalle1" placeholder="Ingrese un detalle" required></textarea>
                    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" name="detalle1" id="detalle1" required>-->
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="nuevoRole()"><span class='fa fa-save'></span> Guardar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><span class='fa fa-close'></span> Cerrar</button>  
                </div>
            </form>               
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Ahora bien, tengo este codigo de javascript, para obener los datos de html.

```
function nuevoRole(){

  var tipo_role=document.getElementById('tiporole1').value;
  var detalle=document.getElementById('detalle1').value;

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'./core/ajax/add_role.php',
    data:'tipo_role='+tipo_role+'&detalle='+detalle,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
    },
    success:function(msg){
        if(msg == 'ok'){
            $('tiporole1').val('');
            $('detalle1').val('');
            //$('#inputMessage').val('');
            $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Nuevo Role Agregdo.</p>');
        }else{
            $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Error, please try again.</span>');
        }
        $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
    }
});}
```

Ahora, el codigo no php es este.

```
<?php  
require_once ('../core/clases/Role.php');

if (isset($_POST['tiporole1'])) {
    $tipo=$_POST['tiporole1'];
}
if (isset($_POST['detalle1'])) {
    $detalle=$_POST['detalle1'];
}
$id_user = 1;
$created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$user = new User($tipo,$detalle,$id_user,$id_user,$created_at);
$user->saveUser(); ?>
```

Entonces, para terminar, el navegador en modo depurar me dice error 404, pero la ruta del directorio mia es asi:

> core/
>
> > ajax/
> >
> > > add_role.php
> > >       clases/
> > >       Role.php
> > >       Conexion.php
>
> js/
>
> > funciones.js  //Aqui tengo el script de js
>
> module/
>
> > role/
> >
> > > view.php  //aqui es la vista donde en el boton llamo a el modal.

Comment: no encuentra la pagina, fijate en el network a donde estas mandando los datos

Comment: si corrrecto, estuve revisando la ruta pero me indica el problema en la ruta actual donde esta la view.php, ejemplo:

Comment: main.php?module=role/core/ajax/add_role.php